# Is It Possible *.subdomain.domain.com Redirection?

Tags: iis-7, dns, subdomain

I am trying to create wild card sub-domains on one sub-domain with the help of this article

http://dirk.net/2008/05/28/wildcard-host-header-binding-and-subdomains-with-iis7/

I set everything but when I am visiting **example.subdomain.domain.com** then I am getting "**This webpage is not available**"

Comment: can you ping example.subdomain.domain.com?

Comment: "This webpage is not available" is not a useful error message. You need something more (but it's the fault of web browser software: all of them seem to emit vague unuseful error messages like "no such host" or "connection refused", although some are better than others).